# Is there a way to turn an HD TV into a smaller computer monitor?

Tags: display, resolution

So my 24 inch monitor died and all I found at home was an old 35 inch full HD 50HZ television which hadn't been used for a long time. I tried setting it up but because of its size and the fact that it only can do full HD it was very noisy. I am curious if there is a way to make these old TVs a semi-good monitor, like cropping the screen to make it 24 inchish or any other solution to get rid of the noisiness. Thank you in advance!

(I have an nvidia GPU and I tried the nvidia control panel but couldn't find anything that could solve the problem)

Comment: There's nothing you can do with it. TVs are nowhere near as sharp as monitors. If you reduce the picture size, all you'll have is fewer dots on screen representing the same number of pixels - which will probably make it even worse.

Comment: Old TVs have [overscan](https://build.com.au/what-overscan), which controls whether the image is scaled (or has black bars, 'underscan'). With overscan off the screen should show the pixel size sent by your computer, so you can show a particular size image centred on the screen by adjusting your OS's output pixel size. You'll want to adjust the sub-pixel presentation by your OS.

Comment: Also: if you're using the VGA cable, switch to HDMI.

Comment: Every time I read "old TV", I think about CRT. I guess it's now the time when "full HD" is old. Oh my, *I'm old*. :)

Comment: I use a cheap 24'' TV(~6 year old) to plug my laptop in via HDMI and it looks very crisp. In fact, I'd say it's perfect.

Comment: I've on and off been trying to get an old plasma TV usable as a monitor. In theory it does 1024x768 and looks like trash and 600x480 which looks great. Only the aspect ratio makes everything look fat at either resolution

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I thought you shouldn't use plasma tvs as monitors because of the tendancy to burn-in still images. I've never had one myself.

Comment: Well I wanted to watch movies on it :D

Comment: You should provide a picture of this "noisiness". As it stands it could be anything.

Comment: Can you clarify (by editing your question): (1) if the TV is an LCD (flat) screen, or an older CRT (big lumpy box)? (2) how you connected your computer to the TV (VGA, DVI, HDMI...)? If you have the reference for the TV it might help. A picture of the result would be interesting as well.

Comment: Note that I've recently seen screens which had a "sharpness" setting (with a value of 10/100 by default) which made sharp images (text, UI elements...) quite blurry. Setting "sharpness" to 0 suddenly restored a perfect image!

Comment: Voting to close. This question is unanswerable and produces nothing but conjecture answers. Really not sure why it ever made it to the HNQ.

Comment: "it only can do full HD" - What resolution was your 24 inch monitor? (Most 24 inch monitors are "only" full HD as well.) If you were to somehow reduce a 35 inch (LCD) screen from 35 to 24 inch then you are going to get considerably less than "full HD" picture. The pixel density on screen is _fixed_; it's not dynamic.

Answer (score 27):

This is a general answer that applies to using TVs as computer monitors in general.

- If the TV has a digital input (HDMI, DisplayPort or DVI) use that. Never use the VGA input on a TV unless there is no other option available.
- Most TVs have "image quality improvement" settings somewhere in their menu. You want these to be OFF when using a TV as monitor because the computer already provides a "best quality" signal. Any further processing by the TV will only degrade quality instead of improving it.
  (This is often the most noticeable reason for a "noisy" looking image.)
- As @pbhj already mentioned in the comments you don't want the TV to do any sort of scaling/clipping on the computer image as that introduces noise/blurriness too. So you will want to disable over-scan and may have to experiment with display ratio (4:3, 16:9, 16:10) and various settings for letterbox/cinema display.
- Some TVs have a pre-defined preset mode for use as monitor (often called PC-mode). If that is available, use it. It should make the various adjustments I mentioned in the 2 previous points above.
- If you have your Operating System set to scale its display to more than 100% (125% and 150% are common settings in Windows), set it back to 100%. This usually gives a more crisp picture, which is especially noticeable on a lower DPI screen like a TV.
- If your computer uses ClearType (Windows does) to improve text quality you will want to disable (or at least re-calibrate) it, because the TV will require different settings than the original monitor did.
  This is not a TV specific thing: ClearType needs to be adjusted for each monitor and display scale-factor (see previous point) individually to get the best results. Many people don't realize this and keep working with
  sub-optimal settings. On high DPI screens sub-optimal ClearType settings are not that noticeable, but it is a lot more obvious (blurriness of text) on a low DPI screen like a TV.

Last but not least:
TVs have larger pixels (lower DPI) than a proper monitor.
This will give many people the feel that there is something wrong with the picture even if they can't quite tell what exactly bothers them about it.
In general this is due to the fact they sit too close to the low DPI screen and can see the individual pixels.
The only remedy for that is placing the screen farther away.
E.g if you go from a 24" monitor to a 48" TV, at the same resolution and place the TV in the same spot as you had your monitor, the TV will have pixels that are appear to be 2x as big.
In order to get the same sort of viewing experience that you had with the monitor you will have to place the TV at 2x the distance from your eye. (That can be problematic if your desk isn't deep enough.)
A little closer will probably still work. For most people somewhere between 1.5x and 2x further way is comfortable. It is also something you get used to after a few hours/days, so you can maybe bring the TV in closer after a while.

Comment: In addition to the above, my old TV had a setting 'game-mode' to disable most image processing in order to deliver lower latency.

Comment: @Pelle Game mode isn't necessarily the same as PC mode (I've seen TV's that have BOTH modes). Game-mode is typically optimized for use with gaming consoles (XBox, PlayStation, etc). These consoles are designed to be used on TV's and have an output signal that is already adjusted for display on the average TV. The PC mode is supposed to do even more than that because the PC will have no idea that it is going to be displayed on a TV. (Some PC drivers may have a "optimize for TV" setting though. In which case Game-mode may work better than PC mode.)